# Understanding escapes used for changing text colour

Tags: terminal, colors, escape-characters

I know that things:

- To change the output text to red, I need output an escape code like `\033[31m`.
- The `\` is the escape.
- The `033` is the ASCII escape code in octal.

But my question is, why I need to use two scapes?
I mean, why I can't use simply `\[31m` instead of `\033[31m`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "escape codes" are simply different things. They serve different purposes!

The backslash followed by a number is used to insert the character with the specified numeric code point. Open up an ASCII table and look up what is at position 033.

Your `[31m` is a sequence interpreted as something special only after that character. It doesn't mean anything special without.

So you need both.

Why? Because someone invented it that way, that you need to send 033 to put the terminal into control sequence parsing mode.

Comment: Jmmm....From what I understood you, for the case of `\033`, the backslash is not a bash escape (as it would be in `\"`) but a way to insert ASCII characters in numeric code.

Comment: `\033` in a string literal is a way of telling bash to construct a string containing that character. Bash is completely uninvolved in interpreting that. Bash is just the shell, not the terminal.

Comment: Wow, I comprehend now. Bash transmits that data to the terminal, which serves as the text input/output environment.